# TWIG Get first letter of HTML after Raw filter

Tags: php, twig, symfony, symfony-3.1

I know how to get the first letter of a string in TWIG

```
<p>The first letter is {{someString | first}}</p>
```

With an HTML string like

```
<p>This is a sting</p>
```

The above would return '<'

Adding 'Raw'/'escape' ends up to the same result.

I need to display that string as HTML ( like with Raw ) but get the first letter ( in the case above case 'T').

Am I using the filter in the incorrect order ?

Anyone knows ?

Many thanks ahead

@Matteo's answer is already close but not quite exactly what I wanted . I may have formulated my question wrongly. Sorry.

So If I had a string like this

```
<p>This is a <strong>string</strong></p>
```

Using raw would give

This is a **string**

Now what I really need is to get the first letter (T) to do something with it  like adding tags around it

```
<span>T</span>his is a <strong>string</string>
```

while still keeping the rest of the HTML inside . Striptags remove all the tags in the string and return a plain string without the HTML part.
I hope I formulated it right.

Comment: Hi there. If you think @Matteo 's answer answered your question (which I think it did), can you mark it as the correct answer. Thanks!

Comment: It's close but not quite what I'm looking for

Comment: Use CSS `p::first-letter`.

Comment: Are you able to click `edit` on your post and re-word your question correctly as per your comment to @Matteo 's post? If not, maybe post a new question. Reading your comment, I still don't understand what you need. Why does `String` have to be bolded - it's not clear.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [striptags](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/striptags.html) filter:

```
<p>The first letter is {{someString|striptags | first}}</p>
```

[Here](http://twigfiddle.com/pk10ip) a working solutions

Hope this help

Comment: This is alreay a great start
But I may have wrongly formulated my question ( very sorry )
What I really meant was 
with `<p>This is a <b>String</b></p>`, I'd like to get the first letter and display the `<b>String </b>` as bold . Which striptags does not allow as it remove all the html string. 
Is there a way to only remove the first tags ?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
{% set someString = "This is a <strong>String<strong>"%}

<span>{{someString|striptags|first}}</span>{{someString|slice[4:]|raw}}
```

You can try in twigFiddle:
http://twigfiddle.com/pk10ip